# using only html page for frontend with web3 or ethers.js

Tags: solidity, web3js, dapps, ethers.js, frontend

I was just wondering, since we are able to write js scripts inside html docs, would we be able to create a dapp with fully functional html front end for our smart contracts?

Or would we need to use react?

If we are not able to only use html and require react or something, else, wouldn't it be better to learn typescript over react as it's javascript with more definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly code a full dapp with HTML & JavaScript only (and probably CSS or similar for styling), always depending on the project requirements. Once you import web3.js within your JavaScript code, you can use all methods from this library and interact with smart contracts.

However, if you already know HTML, CSS and JavaScript, you’ll find a lot of advantages by developing with React (plenty of libraries, component reusability, fast rendering, active community..) and you will learn it quite fast. Using **create-react-app** will simplify most of the steps to run the app.

From my perspective, using TypeScript (with or without React) is the best option: you will avoid messing with types and it will enable scaling the app.

In addition, according to the current market demand, a high amount of full stack blockchain jobs are preferably looking for React.js + web3.js in frontend and Node.js in backend, and using TypeScript in both cases is a plus.